# Why is not these two return of bool equal?

Tags: c, boolean, return

These two return statements does not seem to be equal and I wonder why?

```
bool isFound = false;
return isFound;
```

Returns true no matter the value of isFound.

```
bool isFound = false;
return isFound ? true: false;
```

Returns the value of isFound in this case false.

I guess the answer might be that isFound is a local variable and is destroyed after function is finished.

The return type of the function is const bool but the const doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
bool SecventialSearch(int* arr, int size, int target, long* time){

struct timeval start, stop;
bool isFound = false;
long seconds, useconds;
int* iter = arr;

gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

while (*iter != target && iter != &arr[size-1])
    iter++;

if (*iter == target )
    isFound = true;

gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);

seconds = stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
useconds = stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

*time = ((seconds)*1000000 + useconds);
return isFound;
}
```

Returns true in the following code in main even if target is not in array. Altering to isFound ? true: false; makes it work properly.

```
if (SecventialSearch(testArr,testArrSize,5, &test))
    printf("Is true.");
else
    printf("Is false.");
```

[image]

Comment: Both are the same. And "*Returns true no matter the value of isFound.*" is wrong. "*...isFound is a local variable and is destroyed after function is finished.*" -- Yes, but you aren't using the address of it. You are just returning the value of it(true or false). So, it isn't the problem.

Comment: Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: First code return false. I don't know how can it return true....

Comment: Did you `#include <stdbool.h>`?

Comment: There is no type named bool in plain old c and there are no keywords `true` and `false`. Please try to print out the (integer-)values of `true` and `false` to see, if they are defined strange.

Comment: @urzeit There is a type `bool`in stdbool.h which is a macro that expands to standard keyword `_Bool`. The same header contains the macros `true` and `false` which expand to 1 and 0 respectively. This was introduced in the C language 16 years ago.

Comment: @Lundin: Right, the header file was introduced in C99. It might not be there in older compilers (I wrote *old* C to that I don't have to look which standard intruduced bool...)

Comment: Make sure you test your code with the same scenario when changing that return code you're saying makes a difference.

Comment: @urzeit Unless the OP explicitly states that they are using some dinosaur compiler or a specific version of the standard (by adding C90 or C99 tags etc), always assume they are using the current standard.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm assuming that your variable is declared as boolean type (**`bool isFound`**).**

The expression `isFound ? true : false;` is redundant.

It will evaluate to `true` if `isFound` is true, or to `false` if `isFound` is false.

It has the exact same behavior as just writing `isFound`. So `return isFound ? true : false;` is equivalent to `return isFound;`

The same applies to code like

```
if (isFound) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

which is the same as writing `return isFound;`

**EDIT:** You said this is always returning `true`:

```
bool isFound = false;
return isFound;
```

http://ideone.com/KwmXZb

Double check the rest of the code. This alone will sure return `false`.

Comment: Your whole answer is based on `isFound` is `bool` and it's either `true` or `false`. However, this question is tagged as 'C', and `isFound`, even though is a `bool`, can hold any non-zero value. Using `isFound ? true : false;` to convert a non-zero to `false` is good practice and not redundant.

Comment: There's no references in C so it seems quite unlikely that the function returns a reference.

Comment: @Lundin, you're right. I was led by a discussion about this that started here...